# How to give background color to Group in Constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have grouped 3 textview in a constraint layout. I have background to the group, but its not working.

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
                    android:id="@+id/group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/text_color_3"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="price_tv,currency_unit_tv,frequency_tv" />
```

Is there anyway other round to do it.

Comment: This is how it should, if not working please share whole layout file.

Comment: What did you mean by **its not working**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group is only used for controlling the visibility of Referenced Ids in app:constraint_referenced_ids. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group). Solution is just put views in a Viewgroup. I had to put all the views in ConstraintLayout to constrol the visibility + benefits of chaining views in CL.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/area_range_constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                visibility = "View.VISIBLE"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/area_title_tv"
                    style="@style/filter_heading_style"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/STR_AREA"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/area_range_from"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/STR_MIN_AREA"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:text='@{searchQueryModel.areaMin==null ? "": StringUtils.getDelimeterString(String.valueOf(safeUnbox(searchQueryModel.getAreaMin())))}'
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView254"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/area_title_tv" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/area_range_to"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/STR_MAX_AREA"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:text='@{searchQueryModel.areaMax==null ? "": StringUtils.getDelimeterString(String.valueOf(safeUnbox(searchQueryModel.getAreaMax())))}'
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView254"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView254" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView254"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/STR_TO"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_3"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/area_range_from"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/area_range_to"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/area_range_from" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/area_range_value_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text='@{`(` + areaUnit + `)`}'
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/area_title_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/area_title_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/area_title_tv" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 14):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group), `Group` is only used for controlling the visibility of a set of widgets.

You can set the background to a `View` and constrain the view to how you desire the background to appear.

In the code sample below, after setting the background to the `View` with ID `background`, I constrained the top, left and right sides of the view to the `parent` and the bottom of the view to the last `TextView` in the group, which in this case is the `TextView` with ID `textView3`. I also added a `16dp` bottom padding to `textView3` so the background doesn't look weird. You could also use a [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline) for this.

Also note that the view background needs to be added before the group of views that need the background. If it's placed after the group of views, the background would be drawn over the group (and that's not what you want).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#444444">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:text="TextView 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need of separate view to give background color if its already in viewgroup like ConstraintLayout, just bg color in Viewgroup.

Comment: I understand that you can do that @nauman. But if you want to set the background of the group of `TextView`s separately from the background of the CL, this is how I currently approach it. You could also have a `LinearLayout` with the background set on it. But I think the goal of using CL was to reduce nested `ViewGroup`s.

Comment: this solution keeps the layout hierarchy flat, honouring one of the main advantages of using ConstraintLayout

Comment: What if there are multiple views within the group, and they need to share the same background?

Comment: This won't work in case you have three buttons and you want to give margin top and bottom to the first and last button respectively. View will be attached from top and bottom to the buttons. If you give padding bottom to button than it will apply to button and button becomes bigger.

Answer (score 14):

Though the group is only for visibility purpose but you can easily put a background to group.

Group view doesn't have any width and height, so wrap content wouldn't be visible on actual screen.
Provide constraints to Group view and set background attributes.
Eg:

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="0dp" //match constraint
    android:layout_height="0dp" //match constraint
    android:background="@color/text_color_3"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="price_tv,currency_unit_tv,frequency_tv"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frequency_tv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/price_tv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/price_tv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/price_tv" />

//below are your TextViews aligned vertically
<TextView android:id="@+id/price_tv"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/currency_unit_tv" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/frequency_tv" .../>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This won't work in case you have three buttons and you want to give margin top and bottom to the first and last button respectively. This group will be attached from top and bottom to the buttons.

Answer (score 8):

Group is useful for the visibility purpose in ConstraintLayout. ConstraintLayout is introduced to remove the hierarchy of the multiple ViewGroups(Layouts).

We can simply use  for the background purpose. If you simply have 3 TextView and want to apply the background color to the TextView don't add it to any ViewGroup(Layout), just check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#AAA">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
    tools:text="TextView" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:text="TextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can find the source [here](https://constraintlayout.com/cookbook/background.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use the new Layer that was introduced in ConstraintLayout 2

Answer (score -5):

As per the official documentation, group is only used to control the visibility and you cannot change the background of the views of a particular group.

**Documentation: This class controls the visibility of a set of referenced widgets. Widgets are referenced by being added to a comma separated list of ids.**

To change it dynamically, use for all the three TextViews.

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
textView..setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: So how to change the background then if 3 textviews are chained and within a constraintlayout.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: There are three textviews, not single and all are chained horizontally.